# Charge is not only a scalar (or invariant) under rotation; it is also invariant for frames of reference in relative motion

Tags: electromagnetism, charge, inertial-frames, invariants

I read this statement in my textbook ([here](http://here))

> Charge is not only a scalar (or invariant) under rotation; it is also invariant for frames of reference in relative motion.

I am not able to understand what this  statement means.

Besides, is it always true for every scalar quantity?

Comment: Is that statement from your book? If yes, please specify the name and author of the book by making an [edit].

Comment: Speed is invariant under rotations but *not* under boosts.

Answer (score 1):

The Lorentz transforming geometric quantity is 4-current density:

$$ j^{\mu}= (c\rho, \vec j) $$

where $\rho$ is charge density and $\vec j$ is 3-current density. Charge density is not a Lorentz scalar because the volume element picks up a factor of $1/\gamma$ under boosts.

For a localized charge density, the total charge remains the same, you just need to a different volume to contain it.

In the limit of point charges, you could use the 4-velocity so that:

$$ j^{\mu} = qu^{\mu} = (q\gamma c, q\gamma \vec v) $$

Though:

$$ j^0 = q\gamma c $$

isn't a Lorentz scalar either, but if you factor the $q$ out front:

$$ j^{\mu} = q(\gamma c, \gamma \vec v) $$

then it's still the same "q", but a different $u^0$.

Answer (score 0):

Invariance under rotation does not imply invariance under a (Lorentz or Galileo) velocity boost. For that to be true the quantity would have to be a (Lorentz or Galileo) scalar, such as charge happens to be. Usually scalar is short hand notation for Lorentz scalar.

Comment: What is a velocity boost?

Comment: A transformation between frames that have a relative velocity.